# Passing Servlet Variables in HTML

Tags: html, sql, servlets

Is there a way to pass servlet variables in HTML tables?
I want to pass these servlet variables in the html table spaces I have left in code.

servlet code:

```
int a=parseInt(request.getParameter("pno"));  
String b=request.getParameter("zone");  
String c=request.getParameter("ano");
String d=request.getParameter("bill"); 
String e=request.getParameter("rd1");


String f=request.getParameter("userpass");  

out.println("<table margin-top:'200px'>");
out.println(" <tr><td>P_No:</td><td width='75%' colspan='3'>     </td</tr>");
out.println("<tr><td>Zone:</td><td width='75%' colspan='3'>     </td></tr>");

out.println("<tr><td>Aadhaar.No:</td><td width='75%' colspan='3'>     </td></tr>");
out.println("<tr><td>Bill_No:</td><td width='75%' colspan='3'>     </td></tr>");
out.println("<tr><td>Patient-Status:</td><td width='75%' colspan='3'>     </td></tr>");

out.println("<tr><td>Password:</td><td width='75%' colspan='3'>     </td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can concat it in out.println

```
int a=parseInt(request.getParameter("pno"));  
String b=request.getParameter("zone");  
String c=request.getParameter("ano");
String d=request.getParameter("bill"); 
String e=request.getParameter("rd1");


String f=request.getParameter("userpass");  

out.println("<table margin-top:'200px'>");
out.println(" <tr><td>P_No:</td><td width='75%' colspan='3'>" + a + "</td</tr>");
```

And similarly for other table values.